# Is there any global settings to add \limits to evey \sum, \bigcup etc?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, subscripts

I'd like to put the superscripts and the subscripts always above or below the symbols like `\sum`,`\bigcup`,`\inf` etc, even in the inline mode, but I don't want to add `\limits` everytime. I tried 
`\everymath{\displaystyle}`
which forces `\displaystyle` for all math in the book, but that makes the symbols too wide, which is not wanted. Is there any options which makes the symbols appear just like there were `\limits`? I'm using `amsmath`.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! There are very good typographical reasons for setting the limits to the side of the big operators when used in line.

Answer (score 6):

If you load `amsmath` you can get the behavior you want with just two definitions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\slimits@}{\limits}
\renewcommand{\nmlimits@}{\limits}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\(
\sum_{i=0}^{3} \int_{-5}^{5} \lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{j=0}^{n} \max_{j}\log_{2} x_{j}
\)

\[
\sum_{i=0}^{3} \int_{-5}^{5} \lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{j=0}^{n} \max_{j}\log_{2} x_{j}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you shouldn't do it. There are very good reasons for placing the limits on the side of big operators when used in line. An example is shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\slimits@}{\limits}
\renewcommand{\nmlimits@}{\limits}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

Let's see what happens when the above symbols are set with limits
above and below in a paragraph and how ugly white stripes will
$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2$ spoil your document so that
reading will be hindered. Don't do it in your documents.

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The more operators with limit you have, the worse your document will be.

Answer (score 3):

This should work, placed in the preamble:

```
\let\NOLIMITS\nolimits
\let\nolimits\limits
\let\displaylimits\limits
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

This *prohibits completely* limits to the right, the only way how to impose them now is using `\NOLIMITS`. It is necessary to use the tweaks before loading `amsmath` and it is necessary to load `amsmath` since `amsmath` redefines all operator macros, and this way, the tweaked limits macros will be used. A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\NOLIMITS\nolimits
\let\nolimits\limits
\let\displaylimits\limits
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\def\xtest{
\sum_{i=0}^{3} \int_{-5}^{5} \lim_{n\to\infty} \prod_{j=0}^{n} \operatorname{log}_2 x_j
}

\( \xtest \)

\[ \xtest \]

\end{document}
```

---

**However, please remember that:**

> There are very good typographical reasons for setting the limits to the side of the big operators when used in line. –  egreg

Comment: Did you try it? After an Op atom there can be any number of `\limits`, `\nolimits` or `\displaylimits` commands and the last one prevails. The default behavior is *as if* `\displaylimits` has been given, but this command is not executed, so redefining `\displaylimits` has no effect unless it is *explicitly* appended after the Op atom.

Comment: @egreg Ah, I forgot that `amsmath` is necessary. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Of course `\renewcommand\slimits@{\limits}` and `\renewcommand{\nmlimits@}{\limits}` instead of your `\let` commands would avoid the wrong placement of limits on `\int`.

Comment: All the placement is wrong now. The question says "everything", so everything :)

Answer (score 2):

One hack would be to write:

```
\let\originalsum=\sum
\def\sum{\originalsum\limits}
```

Of course, you would have to do this for every symbol that you wanted to "automate" the limits for. If you wanted to be swish you could do this in one hit with:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\ImposeLimitsOnOperator[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\csname original#1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1\endcsname%
  \expandafter\edef\csname #1\endcsname{\csname original#1\endcsname\limits}%
}
\newcommand\WithLimits{\forcsvlist{\ImposeLimitsOnOperator}}
\WithLimits{sum,bigcup,inf}
```

As I said, this is a hack. There should be a better way of doing this (although as egreg says, you probably shouldn't:)