# Too many Sums: "TeX capacity exceeded "

Tags: macros

I am a lazy student who writes a lecture in LaTeX.

As I need many `\sum\limits` and `\int\limits` I tried to overwrite the command `\sum\limits` so I just have to write `\sum`. So I wrote

```
\renewcommand{\sum}{\sum\limits}
```

Now I get a lot of problems like

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\sum ->\sum
\limits
l.579 $$\sum
_{i=1}^m K_i B(t,t_i) + N B(t,T)$$"
```

Is there a possibility to short the `\sum\limits` command and get no problems in a way I tried?

Or should I define a completely new command like

```
\newcommand{\summe}{\sum\limits}
```

Will this way work?

Comment: See if `\def{\sum}{\sum\limits}` works. But a new command should certainly work.

Comment: Circular definition. But please explain why you need `\sum\limits` all the time. There are good reasons not to use it.

Comment: When you `\def\sum{\sum\limits}`, you tell TeX that `\sum` expands to the *two* tokens `\sum` and `\limits`. This `\sum` then expands to `\sum\limits`, expanding to `\sum\sum\limits`, expanding to `\sum\sum\sum\limits`, ad nauseam.

Comment: @MikeRenfro `\def{` is a syntax error

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would `\edef` work here? Not saying this general concept is good practice, but would it work?

Comment: @SeanAllred well that depends if `\sum` is safe in an edef which depends on lots of things:-) (did anyone mention breqn....0

Comment: @SeanAllred If `amsmath` is not loaded, then `\sum` and `\limits` are unexpandable, so doing `\edef\sum{\sum\limits}` is the same as doing `\def\sum{\sum\limits}`. If `amsmath` is loaded, using `\sum` inside `\edef` will lead to a disaster.

Comment: @egreg All roads lead to hell.  I will have to try out this disaster sometime -- sounds fun :)

Comment: @SeanAllred Well, I was mistaken; `\edef\sum{\sum\limits}` *would* work with `amsmath`. `;-)`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that's what I get for working from memory.

Answer (score 3):

This is as easy as

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\slimits@}{\limits}
\renewcommand{\ilimits@}{\limits}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

A summation $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{n}$ and an integral
\[
\int_{0}^{1} x^2\,dx
\]
also inline: $\int_{0}^{1} x^2\,dx$

\end{document}
```

However the result is typographically terrible. There is a very good reason why limits in inline formulas are typeset on the side of the symbol and integrals have the limits beside them.

If all of your integrals need limits underneath (in display mode), then use

```
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
```

but, please, for your readers' sake, ***don't*** set all limits above and below in inline formulas.

Here's a screenshot showing the horrible appearance.

[image]

Of course a definition such as

```
\renewcommand{\sum}{\sum\limits}
```

will horribly fail, as you discovered, because TeX will continue to substitute `\sum` with `\sum\limits` until exhausting its memory capacity.

You find a related trick in [Is there any global settings to add \limits to evey \sum, \bigcup etc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192756/is-there-any-global-settings-to-add-limits-to-evey-sum-bigcup-etc)

where an example of why using limits in inline formulas is bad, which I include here as well.

[image: example]

Comment: `\slimits@` -- neat, didn't know about this one :) Also, I wouldn't call the screenshot 'horrible' -- even I'm not attuned enough to math texts to find this so repugnant.  There are good reasons, but your screenshot doesn't show them.  Adding a lines above and below your sum will demonstrate this better :)

Comment: Would `\newcounter\sumcounter\def\sum{\ifnum\sumcounter>0\sum\limits\stepcounter{\sumcounter}\else\relax\fi}` or something work?

Comment: @1010011010 What should that be supposed to do?

Comment: Is the question a dupe of the one you link to?

Comment: @JosephWright Not completely. I think this question is silly, but that's another matter.

Comment: @egreg The idea is to end the recursion after going through the definition once, to avoid the infinite loop/

Comment: @1010011010 Absurd.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\edef\sum` in this way:

```
\edef\sum{\mathchar\the\sum\limits}
...
A summation $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{n}$ ...
```

Comment: Not at all recommended if `amsmath` is loaded.

Comment: Egreg's solution is not usable at all if LaTeX is not used.

Comment: Of course, but the OP has `\renewcommand`, which looks like LaTeX, doesn’t it?

Comment: Of course, but the answers should be usable not only for OP, doesn't it? My previous comment is similar to egreg's comment about amsmath LaTeX package.

Comment: The question is undoubtedly about LaTeX. If you want to provide a plain TeX answer, declare it, or readers will be thoroughly confused by the horrible failures when attempting to use this code in their LaTeX document.

Comment: The question can be interpreted as general about TeX. Here is TeX capacity exceeded.

Answer (score 0):

When you `\def\sum{\sum\limits}`, you tell TeX that `\sum` expands to the two tokens `\sum` and `\limits`. This `\sum` then expands to `\sum\limits`, expanding to `\sum\sum\limits`, expanding to `\sum\sum\sum\limits`, ad nauseam.

Using the different name will resolve the issue, but I encourage you to not do this.  There are many instances where such a shortcut will break in wholly unexpected ways (since you are using `\limits` without any real knowledge of what it does).

Answer (score 0):

As `\int` is defined `\intop\nolimits`, you have at  least two natural ways of obtaining limits placed where you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
\int_{0}^{1}1\,dx
\]

\def\Int{\int\limits}

\[
\Int_{0}^{1}1\,dx
\]

\let\uglyamericanint\int
\def\int{\intop\limits}

\[
\int_{0}^{1}1\,dx
\]


\end{document}
```

[image]

(I have no tools to crop the picture now).

Comment: even if you do have tools to crop, it becomes easier if you have `\thispagestyle{empty}`.