# Limits position of new defined large operators

Tags: fonts, math-operators

It is possible to introduce new large operators by using the command,

```
\DeclareMathSymbol {⟨symbol⟩} {\mathop} {⟨sym-font⟩} {⟨slot⟩}
```

I wonder if it is possible to change their **default** limits position from the premable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do similarly to what the LaTeX kernel does for `\int`:

```
% fontmath.ltx, line 268:
\DeclareMathSymbol{\intop}{\mathop}{largesymbols}{"52}
    \def\int{\intop\nolimits}
```

This exploits the fact that after an Op atom you can have as many `\limits`, \nolimits or `\displaylimits` commands as you want and the last one wins.

With `amsmath` there are more features. For instance `\sum` is defined as

```
\DOTSB\sum@\slimits@
```

where `\sum@` takes the role of `\intop` in the code above. The macro `\slimits@` usually means `\displaylimits`, but with the option `nosumlimits` it means `\nolimits`.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you have also `\ilimits@` (that's used for integrals).

If your aim is to make sure that `\sum` always has limits above and below even in inline formula, please, don't pursue it. Your readers will be grateful, see [Is there any global settings to add \limits to evey \sum, \bigcup etc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192756/is-there-any-global-settings-to-add-limits-to-evey-sum-bigcup-etc)